# How to use Vue web components (generated by Vue-CLI 3) inside another Vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli-3

I Can Use web-components that generated by Vue-CLI 3 build command (`vue-cli-service build --target wc --name foo ./src/App.vue`) as a stand-alone
component in a webpage like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="./foo.js"></script>

<foo></foo>
```

BUT When I import this component inside another Vue project:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import foo from 'foo'
```

I get this Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

The [Vue CLI 3 documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component) says that:

> In web component mode, Vue is externalized. This means the bundle will not bundle Vue even if your code imports Vue. The bundle will assume Vue is available on the host page as a global variable.

But it doesn't say that how to fix this problem when you want to use web-components inside another project.

Do you have any Idea?

Comment: Try install vue from npm. `npm install vue`

Comment: @RuChernChong I installed it before and it is working correctly! this error is just for this specific component.

Comment: So you got a global `import Vue from 'vue'` and another `import Vue from 'vue'` in another component?

Comment: @RuChernChong yes but with or without importing Vue I got this error.

Comment: Please post the whole code for the page/component with error.

Comment: Any updates ? I have the same issue @MahdiAryayi

Comment: You should make vue available to the window which is what WebComponent uses
`
import Vue from 'vue';

window.Vue = Vue;
`
You could also make vue an external in your webpack config and then include the script externally.. Web components are not really suited to be imported in a webpack project, better use UMD module or the source directly

Answer (score 0):

In fact the statement you quote means that you do not need to use `import Vue from 'vue'`. Vue can be used as a global variable as it have been added by the script `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>.`

Comment: these are two different use cases! I imported Vue in my project and it is working correctly. this error is just for this component.

Comment: So you include import Vue from 'vue' inside the declaration of the foo component?

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want to use components in another project built by vue-cli, firstly you should have a index.js (or any other name) , export components in that file like

```
export {default as Button} from './button/button'
export {default as ButtonGroup} from './button/button-group'
export {default as Cascader} from './cascader/cascader'
```

then change the 'scripts' in package.json   'vue-cli-service build --target wc --name foo ./src/index.js'
you can copy the dist dirctory to the node_modules of the new project and then use it(but it is not recommend).you can use 'npm publish' it , and in your new project,use npm install it